# How to test the transcoding time consumption of Wowza

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am now posting a RTMP stream to Wowza and pulling RTSP/RTP stream from it

How can I test the time consumption of this transcoding process

Accuracy requirement is not very strict

Comment: Are you looking to get the total play duration for your stream? or for each playback client?

Comment: Wowza trans RTMP streams into RTSP and I want to know how much time does this process cost.